# Set width to <option> on IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Is possible to set width to option? I tried many ways to do that but till now, nothing:(
Only on IE I have this problem. Already tried this:

jQuery:

```
$( "select" ).toggle(
function() {
$( "option" ).animate({
width: 500
}, 1000 );
},
function() {
$( "option" ).animate({
width: 240
}, 1000 );
}
);
```

--other jQuery--

```
$("select")
.mouseover(function(){
$(this)
.data("origWidth", $(this).css("width"))
.css("width", "auto");
})
.mouseout(function(){
$(this).css("width", $(this).data("origWidth"));
});
```

-- css--

```
option{
width:auto;
}
```

--all works perfect on other browsers than IE--

If anyone can help me to fix this I'll really appreciate.

check fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/173/

Answer (score 0):

Try `option { display: block; }`. If it was necessary for alignment `option { float: left; }`